# Remove some tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Most of the ones on the [new tag page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) only have 1 question. Should we remove
[linker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linker)
[stack](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack)
[ue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ue), probably a typo
[constants](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constants)

I already removed [log](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log) on the [one question that used it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33580/whats-a-good-sensor-for-measuring-high-voltages) using the existing datalogger tag. Also removed [nokia](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system automatically removes that that only have one use after a time period, a month to my recollection. No need to worry about it, it is automatic!

Comment: I believe auto **magic** is the term